# Windows Desktop Icon Filename Positioning

Tags: windows, macos, icons, filenames

Is there a way to make filenames appear to the right or left of the file and folder icons as you can in OSX on the desktop?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this handy tool. I have already tested it and works perfectly well with my windows 7.

http://jimcofer.com/personal/?p=208